# How to show all columns in column context menu in free jqgrid

Tags: jquery, css, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I tried show hide column menu described in

[How to change column name in column chooser pop up in jqgrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29365758/how-to-change-column-name-in-column-chooser-pop-up-in-jqgrid)

If there are more columns than fits to crenn in context menu, remaining columns are not shown.

How to allow to toggle all columns: how to make column menu multi-column and add scrollbar or other idea ?

**Update**

Customers table contains more columns if fits to menu. Remaining columns cannot selected.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what is " fits to crenn". Where the scrollbar should be added? Is it the same problem like in [the issue](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues/39) or it's another problem?

Comment: It is another problem. I updated question and provided image. End of context menu is marked with red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted updated version of `jquery.jqgrid.showhidecolumnmenu.js` to the [github](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). It should solve the described problems.

Comment: Thank you. It is working. Grid state is saved in localstorage using code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422878/persisting-jqgrid-column-preferences  Sometimes selected columns using ColumnMenu are saved and sometimes not. How to save selected columns always ? It there some callback which can used for saving or other way ? Or is state persistence already included in free jqgrid or its plugins?

Comment: Selected rows are saved also using code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545953/how-to-persist-current-row-in-jqgrid

Comment: @You are welcome! I think that the problem with saving of `hidden` state of columns is *another problem*.  `showHideColumnMenu` just uses `showCol`/`hideCol`.  So if one would use `onShowHideCol` callback or `jqGridShowHideCol` event then one could detect correctly the changes of the `hidden` state of columns.

Comment: I used `$.extend(true, $.jgrid.defaults, { onShowHideCol: saveWindowState})`  Is this OK ?

Comment: @Andrus: It looks good, but everything need be tested. I personally prefer don't use callbacks for common settings, because you can don't detect the situation, that somebody else (or you in some grid) will do use the same callback `onShowHideCol`. Such using sill overwrite `onShowHideCol: saveWindowState` and the grid will don't save the state on hiding/showing the rows. I would prefer to use `jqGridShowHideCol` event instead.